# Variable precedence (global in node js?)

Tags: node.js

```
"use strict";

var Tabletop = require("tabletop");
var base64 = require('base-64');


Tabletop.init( { key: 'xxxxxg46hgfjd',
                   callback: showInfo,
                   simpleSheet: true } )

function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
       console.log(data);
       console.log(base64.encode(data));
}

var vGlobals = {
    dataString: base64.encode(data)
};

module.exports = vGlobals;
```

How can I access the data variable from showInfo, to use in vGlobals? It says that it hasn't been defined.

Comment: can you add an example of how do you want to use it please ? Don't understand what you trying to do here. Thanks

Comment: The showinfo makes it into a json type of file. I want to encode it to base 64. However, the variable data in showInfo is different than the variable data in vGlobals.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong, you can't do it this way because TableTop call your callback asynchronously.

My suggestion (a quick one) :

```
   var dataString = null;
   module.exports = function(cb) {
       if (dataString == null)
           Tabletop.init({
               key: 'xxxxxg46hgfjd',
               callback: function(data, tabletop) {
                   dataString = base64.encode(data);
                   cb(dataString);
               },
               simpleSheet: true
           });
       else cb(dataString);
   };
```

And to get the data :

```
var dataManager = require('./myfile');
dataManager(function(dataString) {
  //here is your data do what you want with it
})
```

You should look/learn more about node/javascript and asynchronous/event-driven programing.

Comment: Problem is, when I use this module, dataString is still treated as null, and not as the base64.encode(data) as performed in the function. :(

Comment: When did you call the showInfo ? Because on your sample you don't so dataString  is always null

Comment: The data in the showInfo function is retrieved from tabletop (an npm module). How do I access it?

Comment: It's a  callback so when tabletop is ready it's calling showInfo, but the call is async so you will not get the data directly. I think your approach is wrong here. You can't make it work this way.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion?